bash run array of files two by two
I've a folder with temporary generated bash script content
I made a script to loop through the folder and execute files two at a time but for some reason it does not wait at all.
#!/bin/bash

set -x

echo "Starting temp runner"

script_dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

temp_scripts_folder="$script_dir/temp"

mapfile -t scripts < <(find "$temp_scripts_folder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sh")

for ((i = 0; i < ${#scripts[@]}; i+=2)); do
    script1="${scripts[i]}"
    script2="${scripts[i+1]}"

    if [[ -n $script2 ]]; then
        echo "Script 1: $script1 and Script 2: $script2"

        echo "execution $script1"
        echo "logs are $script1.logs"
        sudo chmod +x "$script1" && "$script1" >> "$script1.logs" 2>&1 &
        pid1=$!

        echo "execution $script2"
        echo "logs are $script2.logs"
        sudo chmod +x "$script2" && "$script2" >> "$script2.logs" 2>&1 &
        pid2=$!

        # Wait for both scripts to finish
        wait $pid1 $pid2

    else
        if [ -f "$script1" ]; then
            echo "Only one file is found: $script1"
            echo "execution $script1"
            sudo chmod +x "$script1" && "$script1" >> "$script1.logs" 2>&1 &
            pid1=$!
            # Wait for the script to finish
            wait $pid1
        else
            echo "File does not exist: $script1"
        fi
    fi
done
wait 

echo "All scripts executed."


what am I doing wrong?
the script is just
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cd /home/ubuntu/azure/API
sudo docker compose up -d --build >> /home/ubuntu/deployment/logs/API.logs 2>&1 &


I'm not sure if I understand how it's failing (is it not waiting, or is it waiting forever?), but if you run sudo in the background, it cannot prompt for your password and will be stopped if it tries.

it doesn't wait at all

What does the set -x to the top of your script tell you it's doing? Add that output to your question.

I don't use docker so it's not clear (to me) how the 2nd script invokes the 1st script, regardless ... what happens if you call the 1st script from the command line? does it wait for each pair to complete or do it also fail to wait?

Your script's last command also runs in a background and causes a double-fork.
wait only waits for the process specified and not the process's possible children.
sudo docker compose up -d --build >> /home/ubuntu/deployment/logs/API.logs 2>&1 &

Remove the &.
As an aside make sure sudo won't ask for a password.
Your script also assumes sudo chmod +x "$script1" never fails.  I recommend separating it as a command and exit the script if it returns a nonzero.  Something like:
function die {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2
    exit "${2-1}"
}

sudo chmod +x "$script1" || die "Failed to enable execute permission of '$script'."

The last wait also seems useless.

I need to run the scripts two by two at the same time

@mohamednaser Yes I wasn't referring to that as the double-fork. Understand what your secondary script is doing.
